# CSS & JS libraries not serving to browsers

Tags: javascript, css, apache, browser-cache

I know browsers will send an if-modified-since header (with timestamp), to keep an updated cache of `css` and `js` files.

So, I've run into an issue with loading some random css and js files, for the first time, when a specific page loads.

I'm loading one specific page with jQuery's `html()` API.
In a nutshell, I'm simply replacing a nice portion of my current `index.html` with `snippet.html`  (nothing that jquery can't handle)

The catch is I'm including some `js` and `css` files with `snippet.html`

Watching my browser load the files, and watching my apache request logs, I clearly see hit and miss requests with these files inside `snippet.html`

snippet.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts/lib1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts/lib2.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/libs.css"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Whatever I do here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>......</head>

  <div id="loadshippets"> <!-- later, load snippet.html into here --></div>

</html>
```

If I hard-refresh my browsers, the libraries load fine and dandy.
However, if I clear my cache and I attempt to load `snippet.html` into the `<div id="loadshippets">` I run into the same problem.

All I can deduce is that the `html()` API has limitations with browsers.

I can always load those libaries inside `index.html`, but I'm looking to understand this outcome first.  (I may load random libraries later on, and not want them part of the general package)

Anyone see why my `lib1.js`, `lib2.js`, and `libs.css` would be ignored by the browsers?
(tested in Chrome and FF)

If it helps, I noticed in FF's Error Console this message appear:
`can't load xregexp twice in the same frame`

Comment: Hey Coffeemonitor, please include a snippet of your JS.

Comment: you should watch the requests in the browser dev tools; that might give you more useful info than the apache log.

Comment: `type` is depreciated

Comment: @Sean Dunwoody, of course I've googled it.